# Calculate ROI over multiple trades

Tags: calculation, rate-of-return

I'm looking for a formula to calculate my over all return based on N trades and avg return per trade (R).

Let's say:

My average return per trade (R) is 5% and the number of trades (N) made are 100.

What is my total return if my initial investment was $1000 and I only bought and sold 1 asset at a time at reinvested my profit + my initial $1000 after each sell and how can I easily calculate that based on N & R?

This question may seem odd, the reason I have to do it this way is because the only values I have access too are N and R, not the actual portfolio value in $, which would make it a whole lot easier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get 5% return per trade you'll get

```
1.05^100 = 131.50
```

So if you start with 1,000 you'll have

```
$1,000 * 131.50 = $131,500.
```

Comment: 1.05 being the 5%? 1.01 if lets say my avg return is 1%? tot the power of my total number of trades?

Comment: That's correct. A rule of thumb is to double your investment you need the return times the number of trades to be 70. So 10% return will double in 7 trades. 5% return will double in 14 trades, roughly. You can use that to make a ballpark estimate to see if your math is correct. In this case, 100 / 14 is about 7, and 2 to the 7th is 128, which is very close to the 131 that it actually is.

Comment: That's a brilliant rule of thumb. Thank you so much. An additional question would be, how to calculate the same thing given my average return per trade is negative? Do I just do -0.05 * N trades then?

Comment: If you lose 5% per trade, then you take `0.95 ^ N`

Comment: @Crashtor but remember that's only an estimate. Consider losing 2% and 8% on two trades is an average of 5% loss. It's actually 90.16% original left, but with the `.95^2` estimate there's 90.25% left. That error adds up a lot over hundreds of trades.

Comment: Right. So calculating it based on your average and not actual profit/loss per trade is in reality a pretty bad idea? The problem is automating it and iterating over each trade to get it's exact return on a second by second basis is going to slow stuff down in terms of computational power on my server. I'm running these calculations on thousands of trades. But the goal is actually just to attain ballpark figures.

Comment: Yes it absolutely will slow down your server. If you're doing a simulation or a game you can take some shortcuts. For example, you could group them to the nearest percent and multiply them that way. So like 100 trades might be 10@3%, 15%4%, 20@5%, ... and so on, and do the `(1+R)^N` calculation once per percent. In that way, you would have significantly less error and only need to make a handful of expensive multiplies / powers - iterating through the individual trades should not significantly slow your server (compared to everything else it does.)

Comment: Ah, you're also on SO (and a pretty distinguished member at that)! Yeah, you could call what I'm building a game. Never the less – Thank you for your advice!